# Why is my radiobox value always returning Y for value?

Tags: jquery

I have a radio box control on my page.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sendEmail" value="Y">Send Email?</input><br><br>
```

I do a jquery to get the value.
  $("#sendEmail").val()

Checked or Unchecked the value returned is Y.

If I check the property it works fine

$("#sendEmail").prop('checked',true);

but it would be nice to return the value directly.

Guess I am just curious why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.val()` of a checkbox always remains the same. what changes is if it is checked or not. if you want to receive a 'Y' or a 'N', i suggest you either write logic saying something like the following

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#sendEmail').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      alert('Y');
    }
    else {
      alert('N');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="sendEmail" value="Y">Send Email?</input>
```

OR, you can use radio buttons as in the demo below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.radio').on('change', function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Send Email?<br/>
<input type="radio" name="radiobtn" class="radio" value="Y"/>Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobtn" class="radio" value="N"/>No<br>
```

Comment: Thanks.  What is the purpose of the val attribute in the checkbox then?   Is it pretty much worthless?  Or maybe it is used somehow in a group of check boxes?

Answer (score 0):

.val() reads the value-attribute of the element. And in your case value="Y", so that's what it returns always.

What exactly do you mean by returning the value directly?

Comment: I wanted to get the value from the control so I did not have to have an if statement with the checked attribute to determine the value.